# How to handle preflight request in laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework, ionic3, laravel-5.5

I am using ionic v-3 app and laravel 5.5 as backend
I have a get request in my ionic app

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization':  'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token')
  })
};
this.prf=this.httpClient.get('http://localhost/blog/public/api/user',httpOptions);
```

It sending an `OPTION` request first then after getting success response it sends a `GET` request

Now i handle this in my `api.php` file by using two routing as

```
//first routing

Route::middleware('cors','auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
return $request->user();
});

//second routing

Route::options('user', function(){
return response(200);
})->middleware('cors');
```

This is working correctly

My requset header includes `Access-Control-Request-Method: GET`

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost
Origin: http://localhost:8100
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Mobile 
Safari/537.36
```

In this article it says https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

> However, if the request is one that triggers a preflight due to the
>   presence of the `Authorization` header in the request, you won’t be
>   able to work around the limitation using the steps above. And you
>   won’t be able to work around it at all unless you have control over
>   the server the request is being made to.

Is there any other way/best practice for handling this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution .

Created a middleware `app/Http/Middleware/PreflightResponse.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class PreflightResponse
{
    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
    * @param \Closure $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next )
    {
        if ($request->getMethod() === "OPTIONS") {
            return response('');
        }
return $next($request);
     }
 }
```

add in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
'preflight' => \App\Http\Middleware\PreflightResponse::class,
```

But still in my `api.php` i have to use these codes

```
Route::middleware('cors','preflight')->group(function () {
    Route::options('register', function(){});
    Route::options('login', function(){});
    Route::options('address', function(){});
    Route::options('address/{id}', function(){});
    Route::options('getaddress', function(){});
    Route::options('getorders', function(){});
    Route::options('order', function(){});
    Route::options('orderdetails', function(){});
    Route::options('user', function(){});
    Route::options('profile', function(){});
    Route::options('calendar', function(){});
    Route::options('calendarapp', function(){});
});
```